# I'm getting the following error code when I run rankabundance from BiodiversityR package

Tags: r, vegan

I'm trying to compute the ranked abundances of a community data (site*species matrix) by using rankabundance(df) in the BiodiversityR package. But the following error keeps popping up whenever I try to run it.
`` Error in `[.data.frame`(pi, i) : undefined columns selected ``

Can someone please help with what this code means?
I've already specified the column names when sub-setting the data. And the data is also in the right format; I've tried running BCI (from vegan) for the same function and it runs perfectly fine. My data is the same format as BCI.

```
library(BiodiversityR)
rankabundance(alad2, digits = 1)
```

This is the code that I'm running, and the data-frame is arranged in a site*species matrix, where sites are rows and species are columns.

Here is the dataframe, alad2:

```
structure(list(`Alysicarpous sp.1` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L), `Alysicarpous sp.2` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Bothriochloa pertusa` = c(0L, 
0L, 4L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Butea monosperma ` = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Chromolaena odorata` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 17L, 4L, 0L, 0L), `Chrysopogon sp.*` = c(62L, 
64L, 57L, 68L, 72L, 74L, 72L, 62L, 56L, 67L, 54L, 61L), `Desmodium triflorum` = c(0L, 
2L, 7L, 12L, 6L, 12L, 0L, 10L, 13L, 0L, 14L, 8L), `Eragrostis tenuifolia` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fimbristylis dichotoma` = c(32L, 
38L, 41L, 26L, 38L, 38L, 41L, 20L, 28L, 41L, 31L, 32L), H80 = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hemigraphis sp.*` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L), `Ischaemum sp.*` = c(18L, 
0L, 18L, 18L, 0L, 18L, 33L, 26L, 12L, 16L, 24L, 23L), `Lantana camara` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `Leucas aspera` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Oldenlandia umbellata` = c(3L, 
6L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 0L), `Phyllanthus virgatus` = c(0L, 2L, 9L, 13L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 11L, 8L), `Rungia pectinata` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Senagalia pennata` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Senna spectabilis ` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Setaria flavida` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Setaria pumila` = c(4L, 
0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 7L), `Themeda triandra` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please share the code you are running and make a reproducible example.

Comment: `library(BiodiversityR)

rankabundance(df, digits = 1)`. This is the code that I'm running. I'm quite new to this so please do dumb it down if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you also post the contents of `alad2`. Try using `dput(alad2)`

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a data frame, but a tibble. Use `alad2 <- as.data.frame(alad2)` and your code will work.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. What's the difference between the two, if you don't mind explaining?

Comment: In this case the main difference is that if you take only one variable, you get a vector (only "dimension" length or the number of elements) of that variable with data.frame, but a one-column matrix (two dimensions: number of rows and number of columns = 1) with tibble.